# Can someone show me an example of retrieving ticker data by the minute in python?

Tags: programming

Can someone show me an example of retrieving ticker data by the minute in python? I am new to python and trying to retrieve stock data by the minute for a stock. Id

Comment: Hi: Unless you bought a subscription to 1 minute data, afaik, it's not easy to do that.

Comment: There are people here that may help you out, but not do it for you so, what have you tried?

Comment: I have taken a few Udemy courses including one that built a program that uses the iex api, but it only gives current data. I'm looking for an example so I can tweak it, not looking for someone to do it for me. Thanks, Chuck